# Is there a way to block and notify of connected USB devices?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb, drivers

I just read the following news about how connected USB devices can act as keyboards or network cards, etc. and so for example input what they like or change sites to scam sites.
http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-28701124

If the operating system initially blocked USB devices when connected until a notification stating what it does is confirmed, then it would be less of a worry.
Is there a way to do this?
(Windows 7 or 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intel ME to block unknown USB devices and get reports on system logs.
To configure this you can use "Intel Small Business Advantages" or take a look at their samples and code something yourself. You may have a way to do it from the UEFI, depending on your motherboard.

You could also disable unused USB ports.